# Grafana: Adding Plotly plugin via docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, plotly, grafana

Working with grafana using `docker-compose`. I want to add the [Plotly](https://grafana.com/plugins/natel-plotly-panel/installation) plugin so I add to my grafana container service defition, thus:

```
grafana:
    restart: always
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: fiware-grafana
    depends_on:
     - postgres
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    environment:
     - plugins="crate-datasource,grafana-clock-panel,grafana-worldmap-panel,natel-plotly-panel"
    volumes:
     - ./grafana:/var/lib/grafana:rw
```

However, when I lunch grafana from by browser I don't find this plugin available(see image below). I removed grafana image and downloaded new after adding plotly in grafana service, no change.

How do I add this plugin to Grafana via docker-compose?
[image]

EDIT:

docker-compose file modified:

```
grafana:
    restart: always
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: fiware-grafana
    depends_on:
     - postgres
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    environment:
     - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS="crate-datasource,grafana-clock-panel,grafana-worldmap-panel,natel-plotly-panel"
    volumes:
     - ./grafana:/var/lib/grafana:rw

$ docker-compose ps
        Name                      Command                  State                                Ports                          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fiware-cygnus          /cygnus-entrypoint.sh            Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5050->5050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5080->5080/tcp          
fiware-elasticsearch   /docker-entrypoint.sh elas ...   Up             9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                                      
fiware-grafana         /run.sh                          Restarting                                                             
fiware-iotagent        pm2-runtime bin/lwm2mAgent ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:4041->4041/tcp, 5684/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5684->5684/udp
fiware-memcached       docker-entrypoint.sh memca ...   Up             11211/tcp                                               
fiware-mongo           docker-entrypoint.sh --bin ...   Up             0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                                
fiware-nginx           nginx-debug -g daemon off;       Up             0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                                      
fiware-orion           /usr/bin/contextBroker -fg ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:1026->1026/tcp                                  
fiware-postgres        docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up             0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp                                  
fiware-wirecloud       /docker-entrypoint.sh            Up (healthy)   8000/tcp
```

**EDIT-2**

Grafaba container log:

```
$docker logs -f fiware-grafana
Failed to send request: 404 not found error
Error: ✗ Failed to find requested plugin, check if the plugin_id is correct. error: 404 not found error

NAME:
   Grafana cli plugins install - install <plugin id> <plugin version (optional)>

USAGE:
   Grafana cli plugins install [arguments...]
Failed to send request: 404 not found error
Error: ✗ Failed to find requested plugin, check if the plugin_id is correct. error: 404 not found error

NAME:
   Grafana cli plugins install - install <plugin id> <plugin version (optional)>

USAGE:
   Grafana cli plugins install [arguments...]
Failed to send request: 404 not found error
Error: ✗ Failed to find requested plugin, check if the plugin_id is correct. error: 404 not found error

NAME:
   Grafana cli plugins install - install <plugin id> <plugin version (optional)>

USAGE:
   Grafana cli plugins install [arguments...]
```

Comment: did you able to import statistics same as crate show on his own dashboard ?can you share grafana json format ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://grafana.com/docs/installation/docker/#installing-plugins-for-grafana), your environment should look like this:

```
environment:
  - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=crate-datasource,grafana-clock-panel,grafana-worldmap-panel,natel-plotly-panel
```

Works fine over here when I drop `crate-datasource` (which is probably something you mount inside the container yourself? If not, it's plain a wrong plugin ID.)

---

**EDIT #1**

The plugin `crate-datasource` relates to [this unofficial datasource plugin](https://github.com/raintank/crate-datasource). Because it is not an official one, you cannot install it the way you install the other plugins. Dropping this plugin from the `environment` part solves the problem.

---

**EDIT #2**

After all, this question is more of a CrateDB problem than a Plotly one. ;) To install the latest version of this plugin, alter your `docker-compose.yml` file as follows:

```
environment:
  - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=https://github.com/raintank/crate-datasource/archive/master.zip;crate-datasource,grafana-clock-panel,grafana-worldmap-panel,natel-plotly-panel
```

Comment: I started having issue with grafana while I was using `environment:
  - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=` environment definition grafana keeps restarting and never able to pick-up (`docker-compose ps` always shows `fiware-grafana         /run.sh                          Restarting`) until I come across an github grafana issue suggesting `plugins="...` that's when it works.

Comment: What GitHub issue? I can confirm it works nicely on my machine with the configuration I posted. Plotly shows up in the dashboard. With `plugins=...`, the plugins don't seem to get installed.

Comment: question modified to show how grafana behaves (I just change it now to reproduce the issue here https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/7905#issuecomment-493926703

Comment: What's the problem with the container? Check its output with `docker logs -f fiware-grafana`. I wonder why I cannot reproduce this... Only thing different seems to be your volume. Maybe I run a newer version where this was fixed? A `docker pull grafana` might help.

Comment: Please check my updated answer and tell me if you're able to run everything the way you want it now.

Comment: thank you for this help. I must admit dragging you to long discussion, however the original question is about adding Plotly plugin via docker-compose https://grafana.com/plugins/natel-plotly-panel/installation I added as in question but not available on dashboard.

Comment: If you follow my instructions, you'll find all your plugins in place. In your screenshot, you will see that there isn't _any_ plugin installed, not just Plotly. With the correct `environment` variable set, it will look [like this](https://i.imgur.com/nS7srUF.png).